# Performing operations on Django Querysets

Tags: python, django

I have very large Querysets with the following general form:

```
(
    {id: x}
    {termVector: [ '.00035 .00052...' ]}
)
```

If I want to convert the `termVectors` from a `string` to a list of `float`s, is there a standard way of doing that? I've been using the `.values()` method and iterating through the resulting `dict`, but it seems to be pretty computationally heavy given the size of the querysets.

I feel like there must be a better way but I can't seem to find any way of doing it in the documentation.

EDIT:
My current placeholder method looks like this:

```
    for vectorList in termVectorQS:
        termVector.append(vectorList['termVector'].split())
    for x in termVector:
        for y in x:
            termList.append(float(y))
```

It just splits the vector string by whitespace, then converts each string to a float and adds it to an array (termList) that I use for further calculations.

Comment: It would help if we saw the code for your current method. Also, how large is very large?  It a large number of these items or is the string we are converting to floats very large?

Comment: @Zev thanks for the reply, added some info. Also, there are around 39000 items in the primary queryset, and each vector for each term contains 36 numbers. These are then used to calculate cosine similarity between a smaller queryset of about 1000 items based on search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looping again, you can use `map` to convert everything to a `float`

```
termVectorQS = [{"termVector": '.00035 .00052 .000112 .000113 .0114 .00035 .00052 .000112 .000113 .0114 .00035 .00052 .000112 .000113 .0114 .00035 .00052 .000112 .000113 .0114' }]

termList = []
for vectorList in termVectorQS:
        termList.append(list(map(float, vectorList['termVector'].split())))
```

It isn't a huge speedup but this ran in 820ms for 160000 iterations and looping twice was 1.19 s

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful, and every little bit of optimization helps!